# Bluetooth problem with Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: bluetooth, 23.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 23.04 and I've noticed my Bluetooth keeps disconnecting after a couple of minutes. I've tried to re-pair the device again but the issue keeps occurring.

Comment: I'm having a similar experience, but it only seems to affect my bluetooth mouse, not my headset.

Comment: @ubuntulover could you provide logs, from dmesg or journalctl ?