# Xubuntu 23.04 bluetooth - br-connection-profile-unavailable

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, 23.04

I have similar problem to:
[Bluetooth problem with Ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468024/bluetooth-problem-with-ubuntu-23-04/1477015?newreg=099cfce033634b4e9a5c9c5d6726f038)
but there is no solution

I have bluetooth headphones Marshall Major III Bluetooth.

In Xubuntu 22.04 works perfectly, but after upgrade to xubuntu 23.04 no.

It is paired and after computer start it is conected and imediately disconected and few times connected and disconnected...

Bluetooth manager answers me: Connection is not succesfull:br-connection-profile-unavailable.

with this message I have found some answer in arch forum:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270465

so I have set "ControllerMode = bredr" in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
but it not helps (after comupter restart same behaviour) - and other adwice I do not understand :-(.

in dmseg output I have (I thing) found nothing helpful.

but something is in journalctl:

```
    čec 16 15:59:27 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 dbus-daemon[2075]: [session uid=1000 pid=2075] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Manager' unit='blueman-manager.service' requested by ':1.475' (uid=1000 pid=22636 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet" label="unconfined")
čec 16 15:59:27 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[2046]: Starting blueman-manager.service - Bluetooth Manager...
čec 16 15:59:29 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 dbus-daemon[2075]: [session uid=1000 pid=2075] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Manager'
čec 16 15:59:29 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[2046]: Started blueman-manager.service - Bluetooth Manager.
čec 16 15:59:30 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 blueman-applet[22636]: Traceback (most recent call last):
čec 16 15:59:30 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 blueman-applet[22636]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/DBusProxies.py", line 52, in call_finish
čec 16 15:59:30 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 blueman-applet[22636]:     proxy.call_finish(resp)
čec 16 15:59:30 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 blueman-applet[22636]: gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Unknown action ‘Activate’ (16)
čec 16 15:59:30 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[1]: Started whoopsie.service - crash report submission.
čec 16 15:59:31 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 whoopsie[23838]: [15:59:31] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
čec 16 15:59:31 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
čec 16 15:59:56 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 dbus-daemon[1261]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.254' (uid=1000 pid=23807 comm="xfce4-screenshooter" label="unconfined")
čec 16 15:59:56 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service...
čec 16 15:59:57 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 dbus-daemon[1261]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
čec 16 15:59:57 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[1]: Started systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service.
čec 16 15:59:57 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 audit[1261]: USER_AVC pid=1261 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.255" pid=2989 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=23867 peer_label="unconfined"
                                                    exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
čec 16 15:59:57 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1689515997.255:2052): pid=1261 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.255" pid=2989 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=23867 peer_label="unconfined"
                                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
čec 16 16:00:27 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

please could anybody give me any advice how to solve this.

Thank a lots

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
service bluetooth start
systemctl status bluetooth
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

For some reason this needs to be done to properly start the module.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Babs!
it partly works.

For me is enough run command:

```
systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

and headphones stay connected after conecting

but I must run it after each computer restart... so I want do it automatically

after switching on command:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio

● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-18 16:05:23 CEST; 5s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 3140 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9248)
     Memory: 11.5M
        CPU: 183ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─3140 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

čec 18 16:05:22 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[2074]: Starting pulseaudio.service - Sound Service...
čec 18 16:05:22 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 pulseaudio[3140]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
čec 18 16:05:23 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 systemd[2074]: Started pulseaudio.service - Sound Service.
čec 18 16:05:23 lenovo-xubuntu-22-04 pulseaudio[3140]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bl>
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

So I want run it automatically. I have created file ~/.local/share/systemd/user/sluchatkaBT.service

with content:

```
[Unit]
Description=startuje pulseaudio

[Service]
ExecStart=pulseaudio

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when after next restart computer:

```
systemctl --user status sluchatkaBT.service 

○ sluchatkaBT.service - startuje pulseaudio
     Loaded: loaded (/home/fik236/.local/share/systemd/user/sluchatkaBT.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

and

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio

○ pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
TriggeredBy: ○ pulseaudio.socket
```

and headphones are again after conecting disconnected
please colud anybody helps me what is wrong?